# Stakeholders access in team service online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have 3(A,B,C) projects in my team service accounts and each of these three projects have 2(A.1,A.2, B.1, B.2, C.1,C.2) team projects in them. I have 2 stakeholders on B.2 and 1 stakeholder on C1.

My question is, it is possible to make those stackholders to see only the projects they belong to on the dashbaord? I don't want them to know them to know about the project A(with all its team projects) and all so other team projects they do not belong to.

Comment: What's the A,B,C projects mean? Do you mean vsts accounts? (e.g. https://A.visualstudio.com) Or you mean the projects for coding (e.g. mvc, web api). What they can see now? Can you provide the screenshot?

Comment: They are differents projects under one vsts account so meaning I have one account that has these projects

Comment: What're groups that these stakeholders in? What they can see in the dashboard now? The users can't see other projects if you just add them to corresponding teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps to manage users.

1. Click your profile icon (In right-top) > Preview Features
2. Enable Streamlined User Management
3. Go to Users admin page (`https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_users`)
4. Click … > Manage projects
5. Check the related projects the user need to use and specify group (e.g. Project Contributors) > Save changes
6. Do the same for others